# How to calculate the days between 2 dates from 2 successive IDs

Tags: sql-server, date

I need some help to create a new column in a database in SQL Server 2008. 
I have the following data table

Please have a look at a snapshot of my table

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oNwy.png)

In the blank column I would like to put the difference between the current status date and the next status' date. And for the last ID_Status for each ID_Ticket I would like to have the difference between now date and it's date !
I hope that you got an idea about my problem.

Please share if you have any ideas about how to do .

Many thanks
kind regards

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server?  Please remove whichever tag does not apply (it will make a difference to the answer).

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify your RDBMS, so I'll post an answer for both since they are almost identical :

`SQL-Server` :

```
SELECT ss.id_ticket,ss.id_status,ss.date_status,
       DATEDIFF(day,ss.date_status,ss.coalesce(ss.next_date,GETDATE())) as diffStatus
FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
           (SELECT TOP 1 s.date_status FROM YourTable s
            WHERE t.id_ticket = s.id_ticket and s.date_status > t.date_status
            ORDER BY s.date_status ASC) as next_date)
    FROM YourTable t) ss
```

`MySQL` :

```
SELECT ss.id_ticket,ss.id_status,ss.date_status,
       DATEDIFF(ss.date_status,ss.coalesce(ss.next_date,now())) as diffStatus
FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
           (SELECT s.date_status FROM YourTable s
            WHERE t.id_ticket = s.id_ticket and s.date_status > t.date_status
            ORDER BY s.date_status ASC limit 1) as next_date)
    FROM YourTable t) ss
```

This basically first use a correlated sub query to bring the next date using `limit/top` , and then wrap it with another select to calculate the difference between them using `DATEDIFF()`.

Basically it can be done without the wrapping query, but it won't be readable since the correlated query will be inside the `DATEDIFF()` function, so I prefer this way.

Comment: Nice answer @sagi, just a quick question. Would there be any optimisation benefits to putting the next status sub query in an `OUTER APPLY` joined on the main table? Assuming SQL Server.

Comment: I'm not sure and I don't want to mislead someone:) It really changes every time.. Only explain plan of both will give us the answer @BeaglesEnd

Comment: Thank you so much ! I was trying the same concept ( a Select within a select )  but your code is working like a charm :D GOD bless you :D